# Other than WP-CLI, is there a way to install Wordpress via the command-line?

Tags: installation, wp-config, command-line

I've been trying to create an Ansible playbook to install Wordpress. Most of the online documentation I've read, about installing Wordpress via the command-line points to WP-CLI. Question is, aside from WP-CLI, is there a method to install Wordpress via the command-line. Here's what I've completed thus far:

1. `wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`
2. `tar zxf latest.tar.gz`
3. `fix the permissions of the wordpress files/directories`
4. `copy the wp-config.php file to the new WP install directory`

This takes care of setting up the `wp-config`.

However, is there a method to implement `wp core install` and `wp core config`, to add the `admin user`/`admin password`/`site title`/`admin email`, without the use of `wp-cli` via the command line?

Comment: it is possible but not fun. why can't you use wpcli? it is the much easier option as in the end you will need to replicate its functionality

Comment: I would use WP-CLI, it's very good - not just for the initial install but for installing plugins/themes, creating standard pages, etc.  You can run the `wp` commands under Ansible.  Also - why are you writing a new playbook to install Wordpress when there are many pre-tested roles in Ansible Galaxy?  You can get most of the installation done with those, then install WP-CLI and use it to tweak setup.